# Why work can't be extracted from thermal energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

As I understand it, thermal energy is simply molecular agitation, and therefore nanoscopic mechanical energy.

So why can't this form of energy be used to extract work?

I consider here an isolated system, i.e., without a cold source to create work from a temperature difference.

Comment: What do you mean by an "insulating system:?

Comment: It can be used. Such devices are called heat engines

Comment: I can recommend [Feynman's ratchet and pawl](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_46.html) for a better explanation than I can give

Comment: I corrected the typo, sorry for that, and thank you for the link

Answer (score 2):

> As I understand it, heat is simply molecular agitation, and therefore
> nanoscopic mechanical energy.

I think you are confusing heat with internal energy.

Heat is the *transfer of energy* due solely to temperature difference. The kinetic energy at the atomic and molecular level (microscopic kinetic energy), what you call "molecular agitation", is properly called part of the internal energy of an object or substance, not heat. Heat transfers that kinetic energy from a hot to a cold source due to the temperature difference.

You can think of the operation of a heat engine in a cycle as roughly being the result of extracting some of the heat from the hot source performing work and passing the remaining heat to the cold source. For a heat engine to perform net work in a cycle, a cold source is always required per the Kelvin-Planck statement of the second law which is:

*No heat engine can operate in a cycle while transferring heat with a single heat reservoir.*

UPDATE:

Regarding your edits, the proper term for what you are now referring to as "thermal energy" is still "internal energy", not heat.  You still can't equate internal energy with heat simply by referring to internal energy as "thermal energy".

That said, then of course you don't need a temperature difference to extract work from (reduce the amount of) internal energy. The first law for a closed system is

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

where $Q$ is positive if heat is added to the system and $W$ is positive if work is done by the system (e.g., expansion of a gas).

For an insulated (adiabatic) system, $Q=0$ and $\Delta U=-W$. So you are extracting work from internal energy (what you call "thermal energy") without a cold reservoir.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Bob D. I'm a chemist who's probably been abusing heat/IE for 30 years, despite being an expert on heat transfer. So if I have an ice cube I should phrase that in terms of IE but if I add heat to it (to melt it e.g.) I should write that as heat transfer?

Comment: @Gert Hi Gert. Not sure what you mean by the "that" when you said "phrasing that in terms of IE".

Comment: I meant that in terms on energy content of a ice cube  I should quantify its Internal Energy $U$ but when describe extraction of energy from it then it is Heat Transfer?

Comment: @Gert That is correct.

Comment: @Gert Describe heat transfer and internal energy transfer as what?

Comment: Sorry, corrected my previous comment: Would it not be clearer to describe heat transfer as internal energy transfer?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was using heat in the common sense, that is thermal energy. I rephrased the question, thank you

Comment: @Larave See update to my answer.

Comment: @Gert Perhaps you could in the absence of work as in the case of phase change. But internal energy transfer can also come about as a result of work only. For example, if you were to rub two ice cubes together would it be possible for the friction work to  cause them to melt?

Comment: Friction between two ice cubes? What parallel Universe do you live in? ;-)

Comment: Seriously though, if a lump of hot metal cools down by radiation/convection, we have two modes of heat transfer. But why not describe it as a loss of $U$?

Comment: @Gert I'm asking you as an ice expert, not stating it as a fact. According to the Engineering Toolbox web site the coefficient of  kinetic friction ice to ice at 0C is 0.02. Small, but finite.

Comment: Yeah, that's gonna take a LOT of rubbing to melt...

Comment: @Gert Re the lump of metal, why would there be a loss of $U$ if it melts. Wouldn't it increase, and the loss of $U$ be for the radiant/convection heat source?

Comment: Yes a lot of rubbing, but it still demonstrates increasing the internal energy of the ice by work,  not heat.

Comment: I didn't say the lump of hot metal was melting, only cooling down.

Comment: Sorry I missed the "cools".  But sure the heat transfer can be described as a loss of $U$ because the lump of metal isn't doing any work while cooling.  Again, and finally, my only point is we must take into account the possibility of both heat and work when talking about a change in internal energy.

Comment: Ok, got it, I think...